# Why is model loaded in first in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have user library `currentLang` that detect current language of web site.
Also there is model that does request and gets data from.

Request is based on current language.
This is library `currentLang` was set in autoload.
Problem is that is loaded at first all models in Codeigniter, after libraries.
Therefore when I open web site I get empty page, because query is done without params from library.

What I must to change in this way?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which one is loaded first, As long as you're able to inject the current language id in the CodeIgniter instance, You'll be fine.

Example:

```
// Library
class CurrentLang  {

    // A variable that will hold the CodeIgniter object.
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->CI = get_instance();
        $this->set_language();
    }

    protected function set_language () {
        // Some code to determine which language to set (your logic goes in determine_language method in this class)
        $Language = $this->determine_language();
        // then we inject the language id in the instance as follows.
        $this->CI->CurrentLanguageId = $Language->id;
    }
}

// Model
class Some_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_posts () {
        $q = $this->db
                ->where('language_id', $this->CurrentLanguageId)
                ->limit(10)
                ->get('posts');

        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind in CodeIgniter 3x the first letter in a library name should be capitalized.